# How to keep Done button disabled until user types something into the UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6, uitextview

As the title states, if the user types into the textview, the Done button becomes enabled. But if they erase everything, it becomes disabled again. For a UITextField I just added a target for when it changed and checked then, but I see no such method for UITextView.

I tried to implement the delegate as follows, but it doesn't work either:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    if ([textView hasText]) {
        self.doneButton.enabled = YES;
    }
    else {
        self.doneButton.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

Note that on `viewDidLoad` I set the textview to being first responder.

Comment: Delegate methods don't get called if you aren't the thing's delegate...

Comment: What exactly doesnt work? Does the method never ge called or the method hasText doesnt seem to work? Try placing a break point to see if your method is getting called. If it isn't maybe you didnt set you viewController as the textView's delegate like others said.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to set the delegate. Very well, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UITextViewDelegate`'s `– textViewDidChange:` method, as you already have.
You also must first set the `textView`'s delegate property to the instance of a class that is conforming to the delegate protocol, and implementing this method.

Usually you set `textView.delegate = self;` and conform to the protocol in the .h file by adding `<UITextViewDelegate>` after the superclass name.